# InfluxDB2 / Grafana : how can we filter a list of tag values with flux

Tags: grafana, influxdb, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

InfluxDB2 flux language provides a convenient way to get all the tags values for a specific bucket/measurement combination, using the *schema.measurementTagValues* function.
The problem is that the documentation doesn't mention how to filter this list to keep only the tag values that match a certain criteria.
**Example :** 
With the following query, I can get all the transaction tag values :

```
import "influxdata/influxdb/schema"

schema.measurementTagValues(
    bucket: "jmeter",
    measurement: "jmeter",
    tag: "transaction",
)
```

The schema contains another tag named "application". I want to get all the transactions for a specific application, not all of them.
How can we achieve this with flux?
The same request in InfluxQL would be pretty straightforward :
`SHOW TAG VALUES FROM "jmeter" WITH KEY = "transaction" WHERE "application" = $application`

The goal is to create Grafana dynamic dropdown lists like this one :
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use `schema.tagValues()` instead of `schema.measurementTagValues()` you can define a predicate function that filters you results. In your example:

```
import "influxdata/influxdb/schema"

schema.tagValues(
    bucket: "jmeter",
    tag: "transaction",
    predicate: (r) => r._measurement == "jmeter" and r.application == ${application:doublequote},
    start: -3000d
)
```

As you see you need to define a time range for this function. You can use the timerange variables of the grafana dashboard here (`v.timeRangeStart` and `v.timeRangeStop`) if suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks oidamo, that helped me out.
I found that predicate function also works on schema.fieldKeys() and you don't need to define a time range for that:

```py
import "influxdata/influxdb/schema"

schema.fieldKeys(bucket: "mucketname", predicate: (r) => r._field == "fieldkeyname" or r._field ==  "fieldkeyname2")
```

that returns two specific fieldkeys